# Responsive issue - HTML

Tags: html, css

Please check the below code, its working in full desktop view, When i trying to check it in responsive screen the .topHeader not occupying full width. I have tried width: 100% but no luck, please any one fix this. Thank you.

```css
.clearfix:before, .wrapper:before {
 display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.clearfix:after, .wrapper:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }

.topHeader
{ 
background-color:#E8999A;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
.wrapper
{
 width: 1100px;
 margin:0px auto;
}
.headerLeft
{
 float:left;
}
#logo {padding:20px 0px;}
#logo img {width: 200px;}
```

```html
<div class="topHeader">
     <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="headerLeft">
             <div id="logo">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div> 
 <!--End Header -->
```

Comment: What do you mean with the top header not taking full width? See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpsp5ogp/), it's working for me.

Comment: I guess that's because your `.wrapper` is  1100px...

Comment: Link to the webpage?

Comment: @Bastiaan ya its not taking full width of browser. Please check it in your fiddle.

Comment: @techies You mean the margin around it? See sebastianbrosch's answer.

Comment: @Bastiaan till issue not been fixied

Comment: What du you want to happen when a screen is smaller than 1100px? .. Should both wrapper and topheader be max the browser width?

Comment: What is the `.wrapper` for? ... Should it have same width as `.topHeader` all the time?, if not, when/how? ... Why is `.wrapper` set to `1100px`?

Answer (score 1):

Set your `.wrapper` to 100% width, instead of 1100px.

Think that'll do the job.

Comment: its like container, So I have to fix width.

Comment: @techies why do you have to have the width fixed? If you want things to be entirely responsive then the container(s) should be too.

Comment: You could set another width like 80%, your margin will do the job and place it in the middle. Percentage will always be responsive to your screen width...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.wrapper` width for reponsive screen or make it auto:

```
.wrapper
{
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all these people who tried to help couldn't understand what exactly you're looking for and what's your problem is. You have to explain clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Giving myself a try. I added "min-width: 1100px;" into the "topHeader".

And what's the point of clearfix in the snippet? Remove unwanted / unrelated codes for reference. It's confusing us.

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.clearfix:before, .wrapper:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after, .wrapper:after {    
  clear:both;
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.topHeader { 
  background-color:#E8999A;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 1100px;
}
.wrapper {
  margin:0px auto; 
  width:1100px;
}
.headerLeft {
  float:left;
}
#logo {
  padding:20px 0px;
}
#logo img {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topHeader">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="headerLeft">
      <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```